How can I group by different years?
I have to group by the different vendors in each given year by calculating the total sales for those years. I could only get the first column.
Output obtained
query='''
    SELECT ven.nombre_vendedor,
    
    SUM(total-costo_envio) AS año2019
 
     FROM itens_pedidos  ip
   
    INNER JOIN pedidos ped ON ped.pedido_id=ip.pedido_id
    INNER JOIN vendedores ven ON ven.vendedor_id=ped.vendedor_id 

    WHERE fecha_compra
    BETWEEN "2019-01-01" AND "2019-31-12"
    GROUP BY ven.nombre_vendedor
    LIMIT 5
    '''




nombre_vendedor
año_2019




Ana Duarte
2154261.6


Daniel Siqueira
2020503.2


Millena Pereira
2054682.4


Nadia Oliveira
2296986.4



expected output



nombre_vendedor
año2019
año2020
año2021




Ana Duarte
2154261.6
5054009.6
7154261.6


Daniel Siqueira
2020503.2
5254009.6
9054261.6


Millena Pereira
2054682.4
3854261.6
1854261.6


Nadia Oliveira
2296986.4
2154261.6
4554261.6




Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.. You can get some helpful information in Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question. Also, you'll find your experiences at SO will be much better if you take the time to go through the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

the total sales for each vendor are grouped by year, you need to use conditional aggregation. your query to include separate sums for each year using CASE statements inside the SUM function.
query='''
    SELECT 
        ven.nombre_vendedor,
        SUM(CASE WHEN fecha_compra BETWEEN "2019-01-01" AND "2019-12-31" THEN total - costo_envio ELSE 0 END) AS año2019,
        SUM(CASE WHEN fecha_compra BETWEEN "2020-01-01" AND "2020-12-31" THEN total - costo_envio ELSE 0 END) AS año2020,
        SUM(CASE WHEN fecha_compra BETWEEN "2021-01-01" AND "2021-12-31" THEN total - costo_envio ELSE 0 END) AS año2021
    FROM 
        itens_pedidos ip
    INNER JOIN 
        pedidos ped ON ped.pedido_id = ip.pedido_id
    INNER JOIN 
        vendedores ven ON ven.vendedor_id = ped.vendedor_id 
    WHERE 
        fecha_compra BETWEEN "2019-01-01" AND "2021-12-31"
    GROUP BY 
        ven.nombre_vendedor
    LIMIT 5
'''

above query will calculate the total sales for each vendor for each year separately using conditional aggregation based on the fecha_compra (purchase date). you can to adjust the date ranges in the CASE statements to match the desired year intervals.

Sorry @KenWhite  this is my first post, I will take it into consideration.

thanks vivek I was able to solve the problem although I had a problem with beetwen I don't know why.

select ip.nombre_vendedor, a.year, b.year, c.year
from items_pedidos  ip,(
    select pedido_id, SUM(total-costo_envio) AS year
    from pedidos , vendedores 
    where ven.vendedor_id=pedidos.vendedor_id and ip.pedido_id=pedido_id ip and YEAR(fecha_compra)='2019'
    group by pedido_id) a,
    (select pedido_id, SUM(total-costo_envio) AS year
    from pedidos , vendedores 
    where ven.vendedor_id=pedidos.vendedor_id and ip.pedido_id=pedido_id ip YEAR(fecha_compra)='2020'
    group by pedido_id) b,
    (select pedido_id, SUM(total-costo_envio) AS year
    from pedidos , vendedores 
    where ven.vendedor_id=pedidos.vendedor_id and ip.pedido_id=pedido_id ip YEAR(fecha_compra)='2021'
    group by pedido_id) c
where ip.pedido_id=a.pedido_id AND ip.pedido_id=b.pedido_id AND ip.pedido_id=c.pedido_id
limit 5


thanks D. Rattansingh I will take into account this answer I could solve it with vivek's code.
since you use the subqueries if I am not mistaken.
